# Perform commit(), rollabck(), setAutoCommit(false) on JDBC Connection from CMT JTA

Tags: jdbc, connection, jndi, jta, pool

I have created glassfish connection pool with ResourceType as ConnectionPoolDataSource.So, glassfish will use the native connection pool implementation for connection pooling. I am not using XADatasource ResourceType as I don't want to perform any distributed transactions.

My application requires the use of TEMPERORY MYSQL table creation at run time. So I am using 
the below code to get the connection from JNDI Datasource of glassfish.

```
@Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/xxxxx")
private DataSource dataSource;

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
    return con;
}
```

Now, My question is, Can I perform setAutoCommit(false), commit() and rollback(), close() on this Connection object????
In forum, I read that, we should not call these methods on Connection object, if we get the Connection from Container Managed Distributed Transaction (XADataSource) as its involved in distributed transactions.
But, I am getting this connection from non-distributed transactions.So, I can call those methods right???

Other question is, after performing db operations, If I call con.close(), will this connection go back to the connection pool again?

Comment: I think I can call these methods. Because mysql "show processlist" command shows the maximum number of connections as 8 ( this is the minimum number of connections I set in glassfish admin protal connection pool settings page). So I think its safe to call all those methods on Connections obtained from CMT non-destributed.